# How to get instagram profiles access using facebook api

Tags: javascript, facebook, instagram, instagram-graph-api

I am requesting authorization via
https://www.facebook.com/v13.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4000/authorization/instagram/

In response to the redirect url, an access code comes

How to use it to access the instagram accounts of the facebook page through which the login was made? It's just messed up with a bunch of different tokens, I can't make it out

I eventually need access to the user's instagram pages to post to these pages through my service

As I understand it, everyone will have a token that will need to be updated on the server from time to time

Comment: I'm pretty sure instagram doesn't allow any third-party tools to post content...

Comment: You need to exchange the code for a short-lived User Access Token which you can use to query the API for User's IG data https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/getting-started/#step-5--exchange-the-code-for-a-token